# If I have a function that returns AsEnumerable, does it cache all result?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ienumerable

Let's say I have a following method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GETEVERYTHING()
{
     return _db.AsEnumerable();
}
```

then I call the method in my code

`GETEVERYTHING().Where(w => w.Active == true);`

Does it get everything from the Database, cache it, and filter the result or it will filter the result before calling database. For example : Will it call `SELECT * FROM table` or `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Active = 1` in the database?

Sorry for bad english, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The contract does no caching, but the implementation may do something different. Not sure if EF does caching or not, I assume not. If you want to cache it, call `.ToArray` or `.ToList` on the resulting `IEnumerable`. The prevailing warning is that repeatedly iterating an `IEnumerable` may be expensive depending on what it is iterating beneath the interface, the standard approach is to iterate once and store it yourself somewhere temporarily. As to the `Where`, the Linq implementation can often translate it to the database directly via the expression tree, but not always.

Comment: see EF Query lifecycle "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272915/if-i-have-a-function-that-returns-asenumerable-does-it-cache-all-result

Comment: The thing is, when I ran SQL Profiler and used a repo, it had this method `public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>() { return dbContext.Set<T>(); }` and it did execute the query after it casted it. It doesn't quite make sense, but `IQueryable` does implement `IEnumerable` however, I always stick with the notion that `IEnumerable` is in memory and `IQueryable` is expression building.

Comment: So two parts, yes it will hit the database again, but once you enumerate an `IQueryable` entity framework can cache that sql expression so it doesn't actually build another expression (which is the most time consuming part)

Answer (score 2):

calling

```
return _db.AsEnumerable();
```

Does not really get the query to execute since it is an IQueryable, which inherits IEnumerable, so nothing happens. calling .ToList() will however force execution, if that helps at all

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, calling the where method by itsself should not force an execute MOST of the time.

Comment: It is not true. calling AsEnumerable mark that all other linq queries will be executed as delegates and will not be transfered to sql code with query provider.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Arent we agreeing here? All I am saying is that AsEnumberable doesnt actually execute the query yet.

Comment: I wish I have sql express installed in my laptop, I'm currently using LocalDB, do you know if it's possible to run profiler against LocalDB? I asked this question because I can't run profiler against my DB atm.

Comment: @warheat1990 honestly not sure

Answer (score 1):

AsEnumerable is marker that divide linq that will be transfered by query provider and linq that will be executed as delegates.
If you write `db.Where(w=>w.IsActive==true).AsEnumerable().Where(w=>w.IGood==true)`,
the first part of query will be transfered to sql code:

```
select * from dbs where IsActive =1
```

but second part (`.Where(w=>w.IGood==true)`) will be executed as delegate in c# code when you call ToArray(), ToList() or iterate with foreach.

Comment: So if we're going with my code above, the database call would be 

`SELECT * FROM table`, not `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Active = 1`. Everything will be cached including row with `Active = 0`

Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "cached".  Your code did not return collection at all. To get collection you should call ToArray() or ToList(). When you call ToArray() there will be request to db that get all data SELECT * FROM table, but in your collection will be only objects with IsActual=true. All other objects will be dropped.